keyboard rgb light is not working on linux! how do I fix it?
in my physical keyboard has rgb light. it's perfectly working on windows 10 but recently I switch on parrot security os and using that keyboard, everything is working fine but the rgb is not working. actually my keyboard is little bit cheap like $10. is there any way to solve the problem?
